# To open exe of SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, ssms

I'm creating a windows application and here I faced a scenario that I need to open SQL Server Management Studio through C# code. Is there any way to open this SQL Server Management Studio executable through code?

**Note:**
I mean to open Sqlserver management studio.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: What is it that you really want to do? SqlServer is normally run as a service, unless you use Sql Server Compact which runs inside the caller's process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can launch an exe using the Process.Start method, [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

For example...

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("IExplore.exe");//change this to path of your exe file
```

Comment: -1. This does not start a SERVICE, sorry. Please learn about windows.

Comment: @TomTom - No where in the question does it ask how to start a service.

Comment: @TomTom, I didn't say to open a service, it is to open an exe file. I have assumed that the OP really want SQL Management studio to be opened anyway

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class:

```
Process.Start("PathToExe");
```